# I want to create a scrollable dropdown div when user clicks a button

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to create a dropdown, but the dropdown should be a div, with multiple pages inside it. On clicking right, left icons, new page should appear. Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aaodtoh6/4/

HTML:

```
<div id="cel-screen">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleColorlib()" id="colorbt">Color Buttons</a>
  <div id="color-lib">
    <ul>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
      <li>Color</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cel-screen {width:400px; height:650px; border:1px solid gold; position:relative}
#colorbt {position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;}
#color-lib {background:#25d396;width:50%; height:250px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; position:absolute; bottom:15px; right:0; display:none;}
```

JS:

```
function toggleColorlib() {
     var element = document.getElementById('color-lib'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    display = style.getPropertyValue('display');
    if(display == "none"){
            document.getElementById('color-lib').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('color-lib').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Using javascript to make it happen, see if it works for you.

Comment: The css is to be modified but it functions as I want.